# Panel and Controls on it get locked in a MDI in Delphi XE6 Why?

Tags: delphi, controls, delphi-xe6, locked

I have software that is developed originally in Delphi 2007. The software has MDI interface and I have placed a lot of controls in the MDI Parent Form like panels, buttons, edit controls, etc.

Just for testing as to how easy or hard it would be to port it to newer version of Delphi (esp. Delphi XE6) I opened the original project in Delphi XE6 and gave compile command.

At compile time it did not give me one single error and just compiled without a hitch.

But when running the compiled executable I observed that when we open MDI child in it all the controls (i.e. Button, Edit, Memo, etc.) gets locked and we cannot click on them or edit them.

Is this Delphi's bug or something related to new compiler and UNICODE?

Please guide me as to how I should solve this problem.

Comment: Solve the problem by isolating it first. That's going to involve some debugging, and the ability to see the code. Unlikely that you will find a silver bullet. You will need to put some graft in to this one.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the default VCL framework has some kind of bugs because of which this problem is occurring?

Comment: No. I mean to say that you need to do some debugging to work out what's wrong with your code. My MDI apps are fine. What's special about your MDI app?

Comment: I don't think Embarcadero would have released Delphi with such a bug that would cause wide-spread failure. We can't see your code to know what's different about your project. What happens if you create a very simple new MDI app to test it?

Comment: @david - did you convert your MDI apps from Delphi2007?

Comment: @HughJones Why does that matter?  The point remains that the problem is with code that we cannot see.

Comment: @david - yes of course, but it might be helpful to the OP to know that porting of MDI apps from 2007 -> XE6 can be expected to work, if that is the case.

Comment: @HughJones It certainly can be expected to work.  I simple MDI app made in D2007, or even earlier, will port directly to XE7 with no problems. Obviously if you have code that makes assumptions about the size of `char` then all bets are off, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @Yogi - do you have any hints or warnings ? (and, for that matter did you have hints or warnings in the original d2007 project?)

Comment: @David, Yes, I have converted the project from Delphi 6 to Delphi 2007 and now From Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE6. I have already stated this in my original post.

Comment: It is not possible to show the code here as it is very big and I don't have the right to share it with anyone.

Comment: @HughJones, The only warning that I get is of unused variables. That is it.

Comment: If you can't provide any more details then I guess you'll need to debug it yourself. I don't see anybody guessing the answer from here.

Comment: Instead of debugging my code what I did was added two new (T)Panel controls in the MDI Parent. Then I placed a few standard VCL controls like Edit, Memo, Button, Checkbox, etc on each panel.

I ran the software now if I do not open any MDI child everything works as expected. Meaning I can type in each the edit and memo boxes, check uncheck Checkbox, etc. But once I open an MDI child all the controls on these panels get locked. This behavior persists even after closing the MDI child.

Comment: Try this in a new app

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, no problems were found when simply opening an old MDI project (made with D7) in DXE7, compiling and running. Edit controls, CheckBoxes and Buttons placed on the master form react normally with or without MDI child windows open.
To answer your questions,

> Panel and Controls on it get locked in a MDI in Delphi XE6 Why?

Probably because your code disables controls on the parent window when a child is opened. That is however a pure guess, since you provided no means to investigate further.

> Is this Delphi's bug or something related to new compiler and UNICODE?

No, it is not a bug in Delphi. Neither are there any evidence that this would be related to new compiler nor Unicode.

Comment: Instead of debugging my code what I did was added two new (T)Panel controls in the MDI Parent. Then I placed a few standard VCL controls like Edit, Memo, Button, Checkbox, etc on each panel. I ran the software now if I do not open any MDI child everything works as expected. Meaning I can type in each the edit and memo boxes, check uncheck Checkbox, etc. But once I open an MDI child all the controls on these panels get locked. This behavior persists even after closing the MDI child. What do you say of this?